# Unit selection circle

Tags: terminology, selection

I do not know whether it's called a circle, or whether it's called a halo or whatever.

But, I do know that I want to know what is the game development world term for this.

So, how do we call it?

[image: How is this selection halo called?]

Comment: I circle with a beam going up representing the selected unit or the red circle you've drawn in?

Comment: The **green circles** (well, I need the term for it in singular), beam is optional. But if there is a term for the beam also, I would like to know it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would call it a **Selection Indicator**.

The green circle around the ship object as well as the beam and circle drawn on the ground are all part of it. The beam and circle on the ground are there to show the relative location of an object at one height with the location of an object on the ground or at a different height. It's a common strategy in 3D games, for example, Homeworld 2 made extensive use of similar drawing for movement:

[image]

Here are some Google image searches for Selection Indicator:

The blue part:

[image]

The green and red part:

[image]

The green corners:
[image]

**EDIT**

I've found the people call this, pretty much whatever they want.

- Selection Icon
- Selection Marker
- Selection Circle
- Selection Symbol

Comment: Oh, that might be it. The images displaying different types of those are an awesome addition. I will not accept as an answer yet, because my mind still projects the thought that there was a specific term I've heard in the past, and maybe there is someone who could provide it.

Comment: @Tom Good plan. I'll be thinking of more terms too.

Comment: At first I was searching for "unit (selection?) halo". But that produced a lot of google results about the game titled Halo.

Comment: Does not look like people would want to name these with something specific. Accepted!