# How to target an entity that is moving

Tags: game-design

I want my arrow to chase the minion that I just rightclicked on.
I have a Minion Class and an Arrow Class. These are the constructors:

```
    /// <summary>
    ///  Constructs a minion
    /// </summary>
   public Minion(Texture2D sprite, int x, int y, int windowWidth, int windowHeight, bool isFriendly, int minionHealth)

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor of the bullet from champion to minion
    /// </summary>
   public Arrow(Texture2D sprite, Vector2 sourceEntity, Vector2 targetEntity, float arrowSpeed, int arrowAttackSpeed, int damageDone, bool isArrowActive)
```

In the Game1 I have the standard if-click structure and I check if the click is on the minions. But I check this with

```
    foreach (Minion minion in enemyMinions)
```

So - I want to mark somehow the minion I clicked on and then to send the arrow directly to its moving location.

How to do that?

Update:

```
        //checks if rightmouse button was clicked to activate the arrow
        if (mouse.RightButton == ButtonState.Released && previousButtonState == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            //checks if the right mouse click was on a minion and the minion is in champion's range
            for (int i = 0; i < enemyMinions.Count; i++)
            {
                if (enemyMinions[i].CollisionRectangle.Contains(mouse.X, mouse.Y) 
                    && (Math.Abs(mouse.X - enemyMinions[i].X) < vayne.ChampionRange) ||
                    Math.Abs(mouse.Y - enemyMinions[i].Y) < vayne.ChampionRange)
                {
                    //mark the minion that the click was made on
                    theCurrentTarget = enemyMinions[i];

                    //sets the arrow.targetEntity to that particular minion
                    arrow.TargetX = theCurrentTarget.X;
                    arrow.TargetY = theCurrentTarget.Y;

                    arrow.IsArrowActive = true;
                }
            }
        }
        previousButtonState = mouse.RightButton;
```

Comment: You mean you want to visually represent the clicked minion? Like a selected [unit indicator](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/32717/unit-selection-circle)?

Comment: Well untill now I only succeeded in sending the arrow to the mouse location after a click. But I want to send it to a moving target. And its one moving target from several moving targets. So I want to mark the minion I clicked on. So then I can extract the minion.X and minion.Y of one entity - the target. The foreach structure does everything for all of the minions in the list. Cant use it.

Comment: @I.Hristov I think I know what you mean. What you would want to do, is create a variable that is of the same type as your entities. Then, whenever the entity is clicked, set that variable (reference) to the clicked entity.

Comment: OK... Remember to use tags wisely. Your original question just had "textures" as a tag. That makes things pretty confusing. To answer your question, instead of passing a `Vector2` for the `targetEntity` pass a reference to the entity, then you can just get the position at any time straight from the entity.

Comment: Important question: Do you want a "homing arrow" that will follow them anywhere (not necessarily a straight line), or do you want to do a simple prediction of where they are going and target the arrow at those co-ordinates (a straight line)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have understood from your original post and the other clarifications, I think you want to create an Arrow at the position of sourceEntity and make it move with constant arrowSpeed towards the position of targetEntity until it reaches it, position which may have changed from the creation of the Arrow. Correct me if I am wrong.

I see that you are using a float for the Speed of your arrow, instead of a vector.
You can use a 2D vector equal to the difference between the target position and the current arrow position, calculate it's magnitude(or length), and then add to Arrow.currentPosition a fraction of v vector equal to arrowSpeed / length :

Vector2 v = targetEntity.currentPosition - Arrow.currentPosition;

float length = sqrt( v.x*v.x + v.y*v.y );

Arrow.currentPosition += ( v * ( arrowSpeed / length ) );

When updating the Arrow's current position, you may want to have the targetEntity passed by reference, so you will have access to the targetEntity's current position. If you don't pass it by reference, the targetEntity's position will always remain the same and your Arrow will stop at targetEntity's original position.

The Arrow will eventually end the chase and hit targetEntity.

EDIT:

For the code you are using, Arrow.TargetX and Arrow.TargetY need to be pointers, instead of floats. Then, you do it like this:

```
//mark the minion that the click was made on
theCurrentTarget = &enemyMinions[i];

//sets the arrow.targetEntity to that particular minion
arrow.TargetX = &theCurrentTarget->X;
arrow.TargetY = &theCurrentTarget->Y;
```

Notice that `theCurrentTarget` also needs to be a pointer.

You will need to make some changes in how you create an arrow, using the constructor:

Say you have 2 objects of class Minion: Entity1 and Entity2. Entity1 is the source of the arrow and always stays in the same spot. Entity2 is the target of the arrow and it is moving.

```
public Arrow(Texture2D sprite, Vector2 sourceEntity, Vector2 targetEntity, float arrowSpeed, int arrowAttackSpeed, int damageDone, bool isArrowActive)
```

Say you create an Arrow object, like this:
    Arrow chasingArrow( some_sprite, Entity1.position, Entity2.position, ...(the rest of the arguments are irrelevant) )

When you call this constructor, the object of class Arrow that you create will save the value of the targetEntity vector as it is now and that value (which is inside the Arrow object) will never change, even if the value of the vector inside the Entity2 object will change. You need to *link* the vector in Entity2 with the targetEntity vector in chasingArrow. You do that by not copying the value, but by copying the pointer. That way, the targetEntity pointer in chasingArrow will always point to the current position of Entity2.

Change the constructor like this:

```
public Arrow(Texture2D sprite, Vector2 sourceEntity, Vector2* targetEntity, float arrowSpeed, int arrowAttackSpeed, int damageDone, bool isArrowActive)
```

Notice the only modification: **Vector2* targetEntity**. Now it will take a pointer to a vector as a parameter instead of a vector.

And when you create an Arrow object, do it like this:

```
Arrow chasingArrow( some_sprite, Entity1.position, &Entity2.position, ...(the rest of the arguments are irrelevant) )
```

You can also pass Entity1.position by reference, but it works as it is now, since the sourceEntity only matters at the moment the Arrow is created.

If you have any other questions, just ask.

Comment: OK now the most stupid question of all follows - how to pass it by refference? :-)  I updated the question with the code I use atm.

Comment: OK I understand the concept now. But I am missing some basic knowledge probably as the compiler now is shouting smth for using pointers in unsafe context. Do I need to change the code in the Properties section of the Arrow clas that is currently: '        /// <summary>
/// Sets the X position of the target entity for the arrow to go to
/// </summary>
public int TargetX
{
set { targetEntity.X = value; }
}
/// <summary>
/// Sets the Y position of the target entity for the arrow to go to
/// </summary>
public int TargetY
{
set { targetEntity.Y = value; }
}'

Comment: Hmm... you're saying you've got errors? Post them here so I can have a look.

Comment: "Type expected" error at "&" here: //create arrow(bullet) within the Champion
            arrow = new Arrow(Content.Load<Texture2D>("bullet"), new Vector2((int)(vayne.X), (int)(vayne.Y)),
                                             new &Vector2((int)(vayne.X), (int)(vayne.Y)), 20, 10, 50, false);

Comment: "Pointers and fixed size buffers may only be used in an unsafe context" error at * here:  'public Arrow(Texture2D sprite, Vector2 sourceEntity, Vector2* targetEntity, float arrowSpeed, int arrowAttackSpeed, int damageDone, bool isArrowActive)
        {
            this.sprite = sprite;
            this.arrowSpeed = arrowSpeed;
            this.arrowAttackSpeed = arrowAttackSpeed;
            this.damageDone = damageDone;
            this.isArrowActive = isArrowActive;
            this.sourceEntity = sourceEntity;'

Comment: 1. Vector2 is using int's or float's?                             2. I don't think it's a good idea to use new when calling a function. I never did that. Try to use new before you call it.    3. What programming language is this? C# ?

Comment: 1.TargetX amd TargetY are ints

Comment: Also, try removing that new operator when calling the constructor. I think that is one cause to your problems.

Comment: Here it says "Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type"    //mark the minion that the click was made on
                       ' theCurrentTarget = &enemyMinions[i];'

Comment: What type is enemyMinions? Are you using C# or C++ or what?

Comment: It is C#. enemyMinions are created from the Class Minion. Its just that I have a list of them bouncing around on the screen. But I never used refferences and pointers untill now. Atm my arrow is doing what u said - it originates from the champion and then goes towards the mouse location when the click was done. Reach it and goes inactive (which is OK). It seems the target entity's location is never updated. But by adding the code with * and & and -> created many errors that I dont understand.

Comment: Hmm.. I never worked with C#, only C++, but I think those 'new' operators can't be used as arguments. 'new' creates a new object of that type somewhere in the memory and returns the pointer to that spot in the memory and that block of memory must be manually freed. Try removing them. I think it should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the target entity is moving (since you used the word 'chase'), you would have to pass the target entity's location into an update method for your arrow, and adjust the arrow's velocity based on the vector between it's and the target's location.

It's hard to be more specific considering we only know your constructors.